# Puppeteer, checking 200 status of respond in links with opening in new tab mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

A newbie question. Im trying to check status of redirection after clicking on links with opening in new tab options. Code is working for links without opening in new tab but with new tab it always "Navigation Timeout Exceeded:". Help :)

Platform / OS version: MacOS
URLs (if applicable): http://www.endocrinologynetwork.com/
NPM - v : 6.0.0

Code:

```
await page.goto('http://www.endocrinologynetwork.com/', {waitUntil: "load" });
await page.waitForSelector('.l-footer.wrap');

const [response] = await Promise.all([
page.waitForNavigation(),

await page.$$eval("a", as => as.find(a =>
a.innerText.includes("Advertiser Terms")).click())

]);
expect(response._status).toBe(200);
```

Expected result:
With links without opening in a new tab (footer Editorial Board for example) it is possible to check respond status

Actual result:
With new tab links (footer Advertiser Terms for example) it is always "Navigation Timeout Exceeded:"

Comment: Maybe try removing the `await` in front of `page.$$eval`? The typical navigation approach is `await Promise.all([page.waitForNavigation(), page.click()])`. I think it's OK to use a native DOM click but notice there are no `await`s inside the `Promise.all` array. The page has changed since 2018 so I'm not sure this is still reproducible unfortunately.